# why won't the image display as a texture in this web GL?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

for some reason the image won't show and i can't figure out why.

image is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Z3U.jpg.

do i need to add a specific property to the texture or define it differently? or is it something as simple as a typo that i for some reason can not find.

```
    var camera, scene, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh;

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width/height, 0.1, 25000);
            camera.position.set(0, 200, 700);
            scene.add(camera);

            var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
            spotlight.position.set(500, 500, 500);
            //spotlight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
            spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.3;
            spotlight.intensity = 2;
            spotlight.castShadow = true;
            scene.add(spotlight);

            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('apple.jpg');
            material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});

            geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(100, 0);
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.position.y = 100;
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            scene.add(mesh);                    

            var planeTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('apple.jpg');
            planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
            planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: planeTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
            plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
            plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / -2;
            plane.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add(plane);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: 1, antialias: true});
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }


        init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the image is not a power of two. Did you try an image that is of power of two size (ex 256 x 256) ?